# Static object as class member, requiring object's methods are static to use them

Tags: c++

I have a class Tester, which I decided to declare static as a member of a class Foo,

```
class Tester {

public:

    bool test(const Data &d);
};

class Foo {

    static Tester tester;  
};
```

But when I call tester.test(data) from an instance of Foo, the program compiles fine, but does not respond after the call.  When I make Tester::test static,

```
class Tester {

public:

    static bool test(const data &d);
};
```

Then it works.  Why is this?  It would seam that I should be able to declare a static class and use it's non static members, for example, if I had a static vector.  I'm using gcc 4.7 to compile.

Comment: method accessing a static class member should be themselves static.

Comment: What do you mean by "*the program  [...] does not respond*"?

Comment: @Max Member functions do not have to be static to access static member variables.

Comment: @Max also that wouldn't help this case because it's a static member of a class that is accessing it's own method (not being accessed in a method)  So a static Tester still has it's own version of test and no reason that it should share its method with all other instances of Tester

Comment: @CaptainObvlious, you are right, it is the other way around, a static member function cannot access a non-static member.

Comment: "declare a static class" doesn't describe what you have done.  You have an object with static lifetime, which is a member of a different class.  But the class itself is not "static" in any way (`static class` is meaningful in Java and C#, with different meanings, and neither of them would apply here)

Comment: @Max: Unless it does so with the member access operators (`.` or `->`) providing a target object when it does so.

Comment: @Ben It is static in the sense that there is only one instance of it shared by all instances of Foo.  static means different thing in C++ when used in different contexts.  Static lifetime is what it means for local variables.

Comment: @MVTC: The *class* is not static.  Also, static lifetime has the same meaning for local static variables, static member variables, and globals.  They all persist until after `main` returns and the `_atexit` handlers get processed.

Comment: I see, but all instances of Foo share the same instance of Tester right?

Comment: @MVTC: `Foo::tester` is a static member, meaning that only one exists no matter how many `Foo` instances are created.  `Foo::tester`, an object, has type `Tester`, a class.  It is correct to say that `Foo::tester` is `static`.  It is incorrect to say that `class Tester` is static.

Comment: I see what you mean.  By the way, is it good practice for Tester to be a separate class, or would it be better to just have a static member function test in Foo (if test is designed only to test the correctness of Foo?

Comment: @MVTC: If it's only one function, I wouldn't create an extra class for it.  But I presume that's a minimal example of the problem, and not the entire code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you get a linker error (right?). This is because you fail to give the definition of `Foo::tester`. (You're only providing its declaration.)

In `Foo`'s `.cpp`file add this line:

```
Tester Foo::tester;
```

This is the definition of `Foo::tester` and fixes the linking issue.

**Update** Here is a complete example:

```
#include <iostream>

class Data {};

class Tester {

public:

    bool test(const Data &) { std::cout << "Yes\n"; return true; }
};

class Foo {

    static Tester tester;

public:

    Foo() {
        Data data;
        tester.test(data);
    }
};

Tester Foo::tester;

int main() {
    Foo f;
}
```

It compiles, it links, it runs and it ouputs `Yes`.

**Update 2** After reflection on Ben Voigt's comment.

If you remove the definition of `Foo::tester` then the code doesn't link. If you subsequently make `Tester::test` static (as the OP said) then it links again and runs as expected.

On reflection, it actually makes sense. If `tester` is not defined, you can't call a (non-static) method on it. However, if the method is static then you don't need an object, you only need its type to make the call. When the compiler sees the call `tester.test(data);` then (I guess) it only considers the type of `tester` (provided by the declaration) and then the code works.

Comment: He didn't mention problems with linking. He wrote that it seems that the `tester`'s method is not called, which sounds pretty much like an error observable during the runtime

Comment: He says "the program compiles fine"

Comment: He would have the same problem with both versions of the code, if this were indeed the problem.

Comment: @JohnSmith: Compiling is one thing, linking is another. If you try the exact code in the OP, you'll get a linker error. If you do what I'm saying here it compiles fine, it links fine and it runs fine (the method is called).

Comment: Strangely it is working now this morning without the member functions declared static.  Last night, simply deleting the static keyword before bool test, cause the program to not respond.  Now it is compiling and working, but also it does compile without the definition Tester Foo::tester in the cpp file.  I'm going to accept this answer anyways as I had not defined tester in Foo.cpp.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I expected the same thing as you. However, for reasons that I can't explain, if you try the code above but remove the line `Tester Foo::tester;` then it doesn't link (at least with GCC 4.8.1). Now, if you make `Tester::test` static, then it links and runs fine again!

Comment: `last night...` after hours of coding sometimes you're too tired to see the problem correctly lol.  I was also going to post [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7f0e3563436262e0) for the nay sayers

Comment: @CassioNeri: Ahh, because with a static member function, the object is no longer odr-used.  So it's likely that a toolchain won't error out.

Comment: @BenVoigt: That's it. I've just added an update, with an easier explanation instead of using the standardese term "odr-used" ;-)

Comment: @MVTC: This might be a specific compiler behavior. The standard requires the definition. For portability, I suggest you to add the definition (in a `.cpp`, not in `.h` or `.hpp`).